# 'if' statement in promise `then` section

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so I am stuck on what I thought would be simpler and maybe I've just been looking at the terminal too long!

I have submitted a project for the React course I am doing and in the code review an improvement was suggested by the reviewer to add an `if` statement check to `then` portion of a promise.

This is what the reviewer said:

> Inside 'then' part of the promise check if(query === this.state.query)
>   to ensure you are not going to replace the contents to an old
>   response.

```
bookSearch(query) {
      if (query.length > 0)
        BooksAPI.search(query)
        .then(searchResults => this.setState(currentState => ({ 
          results: this.updateExistingShelves(searchResults)
        })));
     }
```

I have tried adding an `if` in but I keep getting syntax errors. What is the correct way to do this?

I cannot add it to the initial `if` in this method as it messes up the first query and nothing ever gets into the `BooksAPI` call

Comment: Probably means something like `.then(searchResults => { if(query === this.state.query) ...`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, spot on. Cheers mate. If you want to post an answer I'll check it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what he means:

```
bookSearch(query) {
      if (query.length > 0)
        BooksAPI.search(query)
        .then(searchResults => {
          if (query === this.state.query) {
            this.setState({ results: this.updateExistingShelves(searchResults) });
          } 

        });
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an if inside then like,

```
bookSearch(query) {
      if (query.length > 0)
        BooksAPI.search(query)
        .then(searchResults => {
            if(query === this.state.query){
              this.setState(currentState => (
              { 
                 results: this.updateExistingShelves(searchResults)
              }))
            }
        );
     }
```